# Extract File With LibTar

Tags: c++, c, extract, tar

I have a little problem when I'm trying to extract a file using Libtar.

This is my code:

```
 int htlp_decompress_decompress(char * filename) {

    TAR * tar_file;
    char rootdir[200];
    strcpy(rootdir, "/var/cache/htpackage/");

    if (tar_open(&tar_file, filename, NULL, O_RDONLY, 0, TAR_GNU) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "tar_open(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if (tar_extract_all(tar_file, rootdir) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "tar_extract_all(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    if (tar_close(tar_file) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "tar_close(): %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting the error "Invalid Argument" in tar_extract_all() function. But I can not know what is causing this error.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: `Fixed the error` - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the man-page, the function declaration is:

```
int tar_open(TAR **t, char *pathname, tartype_t *type, int oflags, int mode, int options);
```

That means you're passing `O_RDONLY` as the `tartype_t *type` parameter.  This is incorrect.  Perhaps you meant this:

```
tar_open(&tar_file, filename, NULL, O_RDONLY, 0, TAR_GNU)
```

Comment: I fixed the error, but still does not work. :(
**Thanks for your help!**

Comment: So, if you're still expecting help, perhaps you can provide more information about what "does not work" means. =)

Comment: Still having the error "Invalid Argument" int tar_extract_all()  function.

Comment: Well, the documentation is sketchy.  Other examples I've seen will pass a value for `mode`.  I think this is used when creating an archive, but you could try setting it to `0644` instead of the current `0`.  Otherwise, perhaps make sure that the target directory exists.

Comment: The target directory exists.
i'll try set to 0644 in mode parameter.
**Thanks for your help!**